# Rails server not responding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I started a simple rails server and set the root url to display an html page. It started on localhost:3000 but when I try to access it using my browser (Internet Explorer 8) it says page cannot be diaplyed. The console is not showing any error. It just says server running on localhost:3000

Console output

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.6 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2016-04-27 12:32:39] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2016-04-27 12:32:39] INFO  ruby 2.2.4 (2015-12-16) [i386-mingw32] 
[2016-04-27 12:32:39] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=5752 port=3000
```

Comment: can you add whatever there is in the console, after you ran the server

Comment: which url do you enter to browser address field?

Comment: Try to type url with a protocol name: http://localhost:3000

Comment: @ Малъ Скрылевъ   localhost:3000

Comment: @kunashir  what protocol exactly ? didn't get you.

Comment: @user2375245, add 'http://' before localhost:3000. Browser took my text like link and hid 'http://'

Comment: @user2375245 drop your firewall, restart app as `rails s -b 127.0.0.1`, enter url  http://127.0.0.1:3000

Comment: What happens when you request that page with a modern browser (IE8 is 8 years old and even Microsoft stop supporting the IE8 4 years ago)? What do you expect the app to return?

Comment: @dan-klasson actually i am using a company server..and i am not allowed to install a new browser..

Comment: You're developing on a server, not your localhost then? Get a lap top or consider changing jobs. Can't develop like that.

Comment: @Малъ Скрылевъ   thanks it is working now..what is the meaning of  ' -b '

Comment: @user2375245 added answer

Answer (score 3):

The most probable problem of that you have firewall and it blocks the requests to server, additionally it could be happened that name `localhost` is redefined, so I'll propose a 3 steps to fix:

1. Drop your firewall or reset it to allow accessing to 127.0.0.1, that should be resolved as `localhost`;
2. Restart app as:

   ```
   rails s -b 127.0.0.1
   ```

   key `-b` tells your server to bind it on just IP: *127.0.0.1*;
3. Enter url: *http://127.0.0.1:3000*